# R: how to combine rows using Pivot_wider

Tags: r

I have a table like the following:

```
A, B, C
1, Yes, 3
1, No, 2
2, Yes, 4
2, No, 6
etc
```

I want to convert it to:

```
A, Yes, No
1, 3, 2
2, 4, 6
```

I have tried using:

```
dat <- dat %>%
spread(B, C) %>%
  group_by(A)
```

However, now I have a bunch of NA values. Is it possible to use pivot_longer to do this instead?

Comment: It would be `pivot_wider`

Comment: Since the data already seems to be tabulated, you could also just use `xtabs` from base R: `xtabs(C ~ A + B, dat)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(dat, names_from = B, values_from = C)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      A   Yes    No 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     2
#2     2     4     6
```

---

If there are duplicate rows, then an option is to create a sequence by that column

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dat1 <- bind_rows(dat, dat) # // example with duplicates
dat1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(B)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = B, values_from = C) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      A   Yes    No
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     2
#2     2     4     6
#3     1     3     2
#4     2     4     6
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 2, 2), B = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"
), C = c(3, 2, 4, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I have tried that now but I still get NA values and two sets of rows for each member of A

Comment: @Alex Can you show the `dput` of a example example data that gives the issue because I couldn't reproduce that with the data in my post. thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was my problem @akrun . My table was gaining an additional column due to being imported via CSV. As a result, it could not merge the rows correctly. Your original post solved it. Thanks for your time